# find index of particular element in multi-dimensional array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I've got a document in MongoDB which has a multi-dimensional array as shown below.

```
{"_id":1,
     "name":"Johnson",
     "card":[
             ["",12,25,"","",52,60,"",86],
             [1,17,29,"",43,"","","",89],
             [3,"","",34,45,"",62,70,""]
           ]
    }
```

I'm looking for a query that returns the index of a particular element in the array, for example, say `29` whose index is `[1][2]` but when i queried as:

```
> db.test.aggregate([{$project:{index:{$indexOfArray:["$card",29]}}}])
```

i got the result as:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "index" : -1 }
```

which is not true. I found that this query method works only for one-dimensional array and I'm unable to figure out how to find the index of multi-dimensional array in MongoDB.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly clear on what datatype [1][2] is, so rendering the desired output is a bit of a challenge.  Here is a attempt to help your question...

**Test Data**

```
db.collection.insert(
{
    "name":"Johnson",
    "card":[
        ["", 12, 25, "", "", 52, 60, "", 86],
        [1, 17, 29, "", 43, "", "", "", 89],
        [3, "", "", 34, 45, "", 62, 70, ""]
    ]
}
```

(Assumes a hard-coded value of 29 to search for)

**Aggregate**

**EDIT 2021-12-09 - ADDED $project TO CAST RESULTS AS INTEGER.  WAS NumberLong()**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind:
        {
            path: "$card",
            includeArrayIndex: "outerIndex"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind:
        {
            path: "$card",
            includeArrayIndex: "innerIndex"
        }
    },
    {
        $match:
        {
            "card": 29
        }
    },
    {
        $project:
        {
            name: 1,
            card: 1,
            outerIndex: { $convert: { input: "$outerIndex", to: "int" } },
            innerIndex: { $convert: { input: "$innerIndex", to: "int" } }
        }
    }
])
```

**Results**

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61b13476c6c466d7d1ea9b5e"),
    name: 'Johnson',
    card: 29,
    outerIndex: 1,
    innerIndex: 2
  }
]
```

Unwanted fields can be supressed with another `$project` stage, but I did not include it here since I was not clear on desired output.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. It worked. As to make clear, `[1][2]` is a Int32 datatype and output should be as `outerIndex: 1, innerIndex: 2` instead of `outerIndex: Long("1"), innerIndex: Long("2")`. Please help me out.

Comment: @aemisom - I have modified my answer to include a $project to cast the NumberLong() as an ordinary int.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kindness. You are great.... God Bless You